# Something Wrong With MACD outout in R

Tags: r

In R, I'm using library: TTR.

My data set For R input is Historical Price of Nifty(Indian Stock Index).

Last updated Date of Available data is 28 Oct'16

Download Link : https://in.finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=%5ENSEI

My R code is :

```
library("TTR")
data = read.csv(file="C:\\kk\\data\\nifty.csv")
s20 <- SMA(data[c('Close')],n=20)
e14 <- EMA(data[c('Close')],n=14)
bb20 = BBands(data[c('Close')],sd=2.0)
rsi14 = RSI(data[c('Close')],n=14)
macd = MACD(data[c('Close')],12,26,9,maType=EMA,percent = FALSE)
allData= data.frame(data,s20,e14,bb20,rsi14,macd)
write.table(allData,file="C:\\Uojs\\emp\\Ram1.csv",na="0.000001",sep=",",row.names = FALSE)
```

So, My Output from this code is

> MACD Line: 1.542329
>
> Signal : 0.974972

But in Google Finance Chart MACD and  Signal Values are different

Link of Google Finance nifty Chart:

https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE%3ANIFTY&ei=uOYWWJn9J4O-uwSYypSYCA

Output of GF Chart (Date 28th Oct'16):

> MACD Line : -19.5
>
> Signal : -17.11

Why I'm Getting such a wired Output, also there is no correlation between this two outputs.

Is there any Attribute, which is Missing in My R code?

Comment: Looks like that in your code  example you import  an csv file with IBM data and then you compare it against the nifty index  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things wrong: 
MACD Line in Google Finance is -19.5 and not 19.5

I used the same data from Yahoo Finance (1 yr NSE data) and the found the MACD to be -19.28 so not much difference. The code that I used is

```
library(RCurl)
url="http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5ENSEI&a=00&b=1&c=2016&d=09&e=31&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"
x <- getURL(url)
library(TTR)
mydata <- read.csv(textConnection(x))
mydata=mydata[!is.na(mydata$Close),]
mydata=mydata[nrow(mydata):1,]
rownames(mydata)=c(1:nrow(mydata))
mydata$macd=MACD(mydata[c('Close')],nFast=12, nSlow=26, nSig=9, maType=EMA,percent = FALSE)
```

Comment: Stock Market Prediction using Data Mining, this is my M-tech Project.Actually I'm having trouble in Finding Stochastic too,I don't know why I always get Random values there, it will be a great help if you can Manage it's code to me.I know asking for a code is really a worst thing but i don't have much resources in my college. Thank you so much.

Comment: I can surely help you with questions...just post them here and i would be glad to help you..also please upvote the answer if you think its correct :)

Comment: Due to less reputation i can't upvote it,but i have marked it as Answer. Thanks

Comment: Please, Can you rectify this code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349698/wrong-stochastics-output-in-r