# Wrong Stochastics output in R

Tags: r

In R, I'm using TTR library.

My data set For R input is Historical Price of Nifty(Indian Stock Index).

Last updated Date of Available data is 28 Oct'16.

Download Link: 
http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%5ENSEI&d=9&e=31&f=2016&g=d&a=8&b=17&c=2007&ignore=.csv

My R code is :

```
library("TTR")
data = read.csv(file="F:\\Project_files\\data\\nifty.csv")
stochOSC <- stoch(data[c('High','Low','Close')],nFastK = 14, nFastD = 3, nSlowD = 3,maType=SMA,bounded = TRUE)
rup = data.frame(stochOSC)
write.table(rup,file="F:\\Project_files\\temp\\stochR1.csv",na="0.000001",sep=",",row.names = FALSE)
```

Output of this Code:

> FastK :0.7988
>
> FastD :0.7763
>
> SlowD :0.7966

But in Google Finance,this values are different.

Link of Google Finance nifty Chart:
https://www.google.com/finance?q=NSE%3ANIFTY&ei=wZ4XWPlVkai6BJvHosgG

I'm Using Fast Stochastic Oscillator as a Technical Indicator in this chart.

Output of GF chart is(as of 28 Oct'16):

> FastK :14.87
>
> FastD :36.93

Why I'm getting Wrong Outputs,Is there any Attribute, which is Missing in My R code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to my Own Question :

```
library(TTR)
mydata <- read.csv(file="F:\\Project_files\\data\\idea.csv")
mydata <- mydata[!is.na(mydata$High) & !is.na(mydata$Low) & !is.na(mydata$Close),]
mydata = mydata[nrow(mydata):1,]
rownames(mydata)=c(1:nrow(mydata))
mydata$stochOSC = stoch(mydata[c('High','Low','Close')])
tail(mydata$stochOSC)
rup = data.frame(mydata$stochOSC)
write.table(rup,file="F:\\Project_files\\temp\\stochR1.csv",na="0.000001",sep=",",row.names = FALSE)
```

This is working perfectly.